safari strong password suggestion on login
I'm working with this low-code platform to create web apps.
The problem I face is, that when I create a login page with a username field and a password field, Safari (both desktop and mobile) thinks it's a registration form, rather than a login form.
So, every time a user wants to login to my app with safari, the user gets a suggestion for a strong password, which is totally annoying.
The user can of course switch off auto fill, but that is none of my business.
So my question is:
What are the tags/classes/other circumstances that makes Safari think my login page is a registration page?
